# The request failed or the service did not respond in a timely fashion in sql server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, windows-services

I am not able to start sql server 2008 R2 service . I cross checked all answers given here for same problem without any success. **I disabled VIA protocal**, still it didnot start. I tried using all options(local system, local server, network service) for login, but still nothing happened. I have SQL Server 2008 also installed and that is working fine without any problems. R2 was working fine , but due to unknown reasons it is not.

I can't uninstall as I can't loose databases mounted in it.

Comment: What happens if you stop the 2008 instance, could you start 2008r2 then? What's the error anyway?

Comment: What do you see running in services? What message do you get when you attempt to start the service?

Comment: @Zane I am getting "The request failed or the service did not respond in a timely fashion in sql server 2008 R2" when i try to start the service

Comment: @dean I have specified error in heading of this question itself

Comment: And my first question, if you stop 2008 instance?

Comment: Yes I did, but still R2 failed to start @dean

Comment: I was aiming at the port conflict between 2008 and 2008r2, seen that happen. It is still possible that some other service has stolen the R2 instance's port. Try switching to dynamic. BTW, you've never told us is it default instance? I guess not.

Comment: The error details are typically logged in Windows Event Log. Do you see any error there when this service failed to start?

Answer (score 4):

Have you checked the credential used to start the service? You may have changed password or permissions for that specific user.

To check this settings, open the Service panel (services.msc), go to the SQL Server Service named as your Instance (ex. SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) ), doubleclick and go to the Connection tab. Check the authentication you provided there is valid, and that the user has all the permissions needed to start and stop the instance, or try a different user.

If you are the administrator of the machine, "Local System Account" *should* be enough to start/stop the service.

Otherwise, please follow the link down here and check in the Event Viewer which error is provided there. If it's different from the one described in the article, give us yours. This could help us help you ;)

*source:
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/03/29/sql-server-fix-error-the-request-failed-or-the-service-did-not-respond-in-timely-fashion-consult-the-event-log-or-other-applicable-error-logs-for-details/*

Answer (score 1):

`Step 1` - Check credentials for service

`Step 2` - Check event viewer and look for error messages it sends.  It should be found in Windows Logs -> Application

Once you see any log events with errors or warnings when trying to start the service, please update the question/thread so we can see and help you troubleshoot from that point.

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you can't uninstall and reinstall.  You could detach the databases, uninstall, reinstall, and attach the databases.  You won't lose the databases.

Comment: How do you detach a database from non-functional instance? I agree, though, that he won't lose the databases if he copy the files and attach, but he will lose some data.

Comment: @dean Data loss is not issue, but I am afraid , i may loose database which i cant afford

Comment: OK then, what's stopping you to copy the data files to some other instance and try attaching them with sp_attach_single_file?

Comment: I just tested creating a database, turning off sql server, copying the files, and attaching to another server without any problems.  
This is no different than when I had a complete melt down of the hardware for a server a few years ago and I had to attach databases from our SAN to a new instance and server.  You should be able to attach the databases to a new instance without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to identify the exact issue why service is failing. The possible reasons are logged in event logs. Have a look at the event logs and post what is printed there. Once the reason for failure is identified then probably we will be able to help you out.

Also, try installing service packs. Because in the past I had an issue with SQL Server 2008 R2 and I installed the service pack. That resolved the issue.